# Does Hibernate cache newly created instance

Tags: java, hibernate

While learning HIbernate I came across this in the [Hibernate official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/batch.html):

> That is because Hibernate caches all the newly inserted Customer instances in the session-level cache.

I am aware that Hibernate caches the entities retrieved but does it cache the new ones as well?

EDIT: newly created instance like `session.save(new Customer())`

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by "new ones".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

What the **cache** here means that after `session.save(customer)` , the customer would still in the `session` object and not removed before the `session` is closed.

It means that if you use `session.get(Customer.class, id)` to get a customer with an ID that is already saved before closing the `session`, it will not cause a SQL SELECT to retrieve this customer from database but simply return the cached customer from the `session` .